# creating database tables automatically in mvc 5?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-database-first

I am working in mvc 5, visual studio 2013 and i am totally new to it. I made a new application and it has it's local db attached with it.

I just want to make my database in sql server management studio but i dont want to make database manually. i just want to create the required tables in sql server mgmt studio automatically and then i will change the connection strings manually.

I need to know the way of doing this, please let me know the steps of doing the same ?

Need guidance. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with Entity Framework. You will need to choose Model first because you want to create your DB from SQL Management Studio.
You'll find a lot of tutorials related to this approach.

[Getting Started with Entity Framework 6 Database First using MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/database-first-development/setting-up-database)